# How to retrieve the value of a parameter in JQAssistant

Tags: jqassistant

It is not possible to retrieve the value of a method input parameter.

```
For annotation the parameters can be read:
MATCH (c:Class)-[:DECLARES]->()-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->(an:Annotation)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type{name:"RequestMapping"})
MATCH (an)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"value"})-[:CONTAINS]->(v:Value)
```

What is the best approach to retrieve the value of an input method of a class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly at this time this is not possible with jQAssisant (it would require to extend the Java bytecode scanner with data flow analysis, which is not trivial).

Comment: Has there been any progress? We are using latest 1.12 release and it would be great to have something like (:Method)-[:DECLARES]->(:Parameter{name:"foo})